# UIPrintInteractionController crashed in iOS 14, It's working fine on iOS 13 (Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread)

Tags: ios14, xcode12

```
    @objc func printData(){
    let pic = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo : UIPrintInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
    pic.printInfo = printInfo
    pic.printFormatter = self.webViewPrint.viewPrintFormatter()

    pic.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Present working fine, app crashing when I have dismissing this view controller.

"webViewPrint" is a UIWebView

App crash log:
2020-09-25 12:20:19.399922+0530 void _WebThreadLock(), 0x13b425020: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
pic.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)

    }
```

From the error it seems UI stuff is happening on secondary thread, doing it on main thread should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

While this crash is quite hard to pin down, I would recommend following Apple's pretty aggressive warning messages when submitting to AppstoreConnect:

```
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage 
App updates that use UIWebView will no longer be accepted as of December 2020. 
Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. 
Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

I had been putting off the migration and also ran into the exact same crash in iOS14. Converting everything from `UIWebView` -> `WKWebView` did the trick for me.

So in the case for your code, you simply need to swap the instance of webViewPrint and should no longer see the crashes.

```
var webViewPrint = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
```